# how to connect iReport with annotated POJOs?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i want to connect iReport with my pojo classes so i can use hql, but when i do the hibernate connection the following error is shown:

unable to load class "mapping class="net.jaffa.school.shared.hibernate.test"

Comment: What do you mean `i want to connect iReport`? Did you use java code or what?

Comment: yes, i am using java code "Gwt", and i want just to create a data source which is an hibernate connection in my iReport

Comment: The `iReport` is a just GUI report's designer. I think that you are talking about the `JasperReports` engine. You can find the [sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hibernate/index.html#hibernate) of using `Hibernate (HQL) Query Executer` in folder *`$jasperreports$\demo\samples\hibernate`* from the `JasperReports` distribution package. The latest version of JR is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/latest/download).

Comment: i know that, i am using gilead for hibernate, but until now i can't create the data source in iReport and i don't know why?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add your .class files to iReport's classpath.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> iReport -> Classpath`, add the folder of your .class files (or add them as a jar) and then restart iReport. That will make iReport aware of your pojos.